# I'm getting an error while excuting a trigger statement

Tags: exception, plsql, triggers, procedure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQgtF.jpg)    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER weekd_tri

```
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON payment

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

IF TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'D') = '1' THEN

RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Cannot make a payment on weekends');

END IF;

END;
```

*error msg
**ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.WEEKD_TRI", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT,WEEKD_TRI***
*can you tell me why i'm getting this error and how to solve this error*

*
*this trigger should not accept payment by customer when made on Sat/Sun so i wrote this trigger but when I stried to insert data on Sun it did Fire a triger ORA - 20000 Cannot make a payment on weekends and I was not able to update the values but apart from that I got the other two Erros ORA-06512 & ORA:04088  **

Comment: Hi Keth, welcome to the SO. Please update the question with what data are you trying to insert or update

Comment: i am tring to update a payment table where i am adding payment details of a customer

Comment: in order to be able to help you we need an insert or update statement that causes the error. And the table design would be nice to have too

Comment: Ya thanks you for helping me ekochergin I have edited the question and added a picture for better undestanding and regarding the table 

 PAY_CUST_ID                                        NUMBER(5)
 PAY_ID                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 PAY_AMT                                            NUMBER(10)
 PAY_DATE                                           DATE
 PAY_DESC                                           VARCHAR2(100)

this is the table description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from your screenshot I see there are 3 error message lines

- ORA-20000 - which is the real error message that has been caused from your logic
- ORA-6512  - service message to identify the line of code error occured
- ORA-4088  - another service message to identify trigger name where error occured

So, the reason why you're getting ora-4088 is raise_application_error command you're using for exception firing. It is just a part of service message for developers

Answer (score 0):

There's no "error", except the one you created yourself, intentionally.

Which day is it today?

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'D') from dual;

T
-
1       --> OK, that's the value you're checking in a trigger

SQL>
```

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table payment (id number);

Table created.
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger weekd_tri
  2    before insert or update on payment
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if to_char(sysdate, 'D') = '1' then
  6       raise_application_error(-20000, 'Cannot make a payment on weekends');
  7    end if;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into payment (id) values (1);
insert into payment (id) values (1)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Cannot make a payment on weekends
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.WEEKD_TRI", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.WEEKD_TRI'
```

Right; that's **EXACTLY** what you wanted to do: `IF` concluded that today really is `'1'` and raised an error.

---

If it were e.g. `'2'` you checked, today you'd be able to insert a row:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger weekd_tri
  2    before insert or update on payment
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if to_char(sysdate, 'D') = '2' then
  6       raise_application_error(-20000, 'Cannot make a payment on weekends');
  7    end if;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into payment (id) values (2);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you ...and yes it works updates/inserts values today but the Question that I have is that I have written a trigger statment where a customer cannot insert/update values on Sunday and in my code SYSDATE = '1' is  SUnday but while i was executing this code apart from the error that I have written Intentionally the other two errors also popped up. For a clear undertanding I have updated the question and added a picture of the error that I got yesturday

Comment: That's the full error stack and - as far as I can tell - you can't avoid it.

Comment: Can you please help me understand more briefly or in an easy way if possible

Comment: What do you not understand? You said that trigger should raise an exception - that's what trigger does. End of story.

Comment: I mean full error stack..?

Comment: These are all ORA-xxxxx errors you see on the screen.